# Facebook popup box not display all

Tags: html, css, facebook

I try embed facebook code to my blog:
[image]

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://codingvn.com/2016/02/01/viet-chuong-trinh-java-dau-tien/""></div>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://codingvn.com/2016/02/01/viet-chuong-trinh-java-dau-tien/" data-width="500" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

I also try: `style="z-index:99999;"`

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://codingvn.com/2016/02/01/viet-chuong-trinh-java-dau-tien/" style="z-index:99999;"></div>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://codingvn.com/2016/02/01/viet-chuong-trinh-java-dau-tien/" data-width="500" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true" style="z-index:99999;"></div>
```

but result very poor:
when press Facebook like button
[image]

when press Facebook send button
[image]

Help me, I tried more than 1 week but not success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this css:

```
.fb-like span {
    overflow:visible !important;
    width:450px !important;
}

.fb-send span {
    overflow:visible !important;
    width:450px !important;
}
```